# How to extract DateTime from a mixed string in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, datetime

I have a vector of strings with 100K row in Matlab. Each row includes a mixture of alphabets, numbers and [./@;,]

I need to detect if these patterns exist in each row:

```
MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm
MM.dd.YYYY HH:mm
MM/dd/YY HH:mm
MM.dd.YY HH:mm
```

example:

```
"Read back and verified on 1/15/13 1935 CM;"
"Was negative on 02.10.2015 @ 2015;"
"Result came back positive 4.2.2016 0821;"
```

The output should be (in datetime format):

```
01/15/2013 19:35
02/10/2015 20:15
04/02/2016 08:21
```

Comment: The second `2015` in your preferred output should be `20:15` (it's a time, isn't it?) and the `YYY` in `MM.dd.YYY HH:mm` should be `YYYY`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Can the `@` sign (which you have not mentioned in your patterns) occur in any of the patterns or only in the one with `MM.dd.YYYY`?

Comment: @PatrickHappel @ may appear in any of the patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following set of regular expressions. I treat two-digit years like this:

If the year is larger than todays' year minus 2000, assume it is `19xx`, otherwise assume `20xx`. Expect problems with this after 2099 ;-)

**Edit:** I had used `strings` as a variable, but it is a command, too. I have changed the variable name to `string_list`.

```
patterns = [ ...
    '(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<year>\d{4}) @? ?(?<hours>\d{2})(?<minutes>\d{2})|'   ... % {m}m/{d}d/YYYY {@ }hhmm
    '(?<month>\d{1,2})\.(?<day>\d{1,2})\.(?<year>\d{4}) @? ?(?<hours>\d{2})(?<minutes>\d{2})|' ... % {m}m.{d}d.YYYY {@ }hhmm
    '(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<year>\d{2}) @? ?(?<hours>\d{2})(?<minutes>\d{2})|'   ... % {m}m/{d}d/YY {@ }hhmm
    '(?<month>\d{1,2})\.(?<day>\d{1,2})\.(?<year>\d{2}) @? ?(?<hours>\d{2})(?<minutes>\d{2})'  ... % {m}m.{d}d.YY{@ }hhmm
];

string_list = [ ...
    "Read back and verified on 1/15/13 1935 CM;"
    "Was negative on 02.10.2015 @ 2015;"
    "Result came back positive 4.2.2016 0821;"   
    "Some test for a year earlier than 2000 4.2.89 0821;"   
];

matches = regexp(string_list, patterns,'names');

today = datetime('today');
currentyear = today.Year - 2000;

dates = cell(size(matches));
for i = 1:numel(matches)
    year = str2double(matches{i}.year);
    if year < 100 
        if year > currentyear
            year = year + 1900;
        else
            year = year + 2000;
        end
    end
    dates{i} = datetime(year, str2double(matches{i}.month), str2double(matches{i}.day), str2double(matches{i}.hours), str2double(matches{i}.minutes), 0); 
end
```

Result:

```
dates =

  4×1 cell array

    {[15-Jan-2013 19:35:00]}
    {[10-Feb-2015 20:15:00]}
    {[02-Apr-2016 08:21:00]}
    {[02-Apr-1989 08:21:00]}
```

Maybe the `for`-loop at the end could be simplified.

Comment: What if there is "at" instead of @? How can I write a pattern for that one?

Comment: Repeat the four lines in `patterns` and replace `@? ?` with `(?:at )?`. Make sure that all but the last line in `patterns` end with a `|`.